# writing in the center

Tags: php, css

I use this code for writing in the center :

```
echo "<div class='pagination' align ='center'>";
```

But it still shows in the left. How I can write in the center.

Also these are the codes for pagination in css :

```
    <div class='pagination' text-align:center>
 <span class='current'>1</span>
</div>
.pagination {
clear:both;
padding:20px 0;
position: relative;
font-size:11px;
line-height:13px;
}

.pagination span, .pagination a {
display:block;
float: left;
margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
padding:6px 9px 5px 9px;
text-decoration:none;
width:auto;
color:#fff;
background: #555;
}

.pagination a:hover{
color:#fff;
background: #3279BB;
}

.pagination .current{
padding:6px 9px 5px 9px;
background: #3279BB;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
.pagination span, .pagination a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #555555;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    padding: 6px 9px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}

.pagination {
    clear:both;
    padding:20px 0;
    position: relative;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:13px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. it's gonna show me under footer is there anyway so that I can write that top pf the footer?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to remove the clear and the positioning and give it some width and `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.pagination {
padding:20px 0;
font-size:11px;
line-height:13px;

    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

This tells the margins on each side of the paginator container to be equal on both sides, so it will center it within its parent element. Please note that the parent also needs a defined width, it cannot be

The `align` attribute of html has been [deprecated since HTML 4.01](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp), so use `text-align: left/right/center;` in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/S8QYy/

Comment: Then you've done something wrong. Look again at the example, everything is in the center.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

`float: left;` from `.pagination span, .pagination a {}`

and add

`margin:0 auto` in `.pagination {}`

Answer (score 0):

if you used to inline css than write as

`style="text-align:center"` **not this** `align="center"`

Replace this  code

```
<div class='pagination' align ='center'>
```

**into this**

```
<div class='pagination' style="text-align:center;">
```

or  **used to may be this**

```
.pagination{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the div to

```
<div class="pagination" style="text-align: center">
```

But the better approach would be

```
<div class="pagination">
```

and to put the "text-align: center;" into the css file. Also use " instead of '

Answer (score 0):

try this...maybe is what you expected to have :)

http://jsfiddle.net/CDcXB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try 
.pagination {
...existing rules....
text-align: center;
}

Also have a look at Operas web standards curriculum: http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/